# Is "no... but only..." correct?

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions

Is it right to write

> There is no money needed, but only time.

when I am trying to express that money isn't required for a particular thing, only time is required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conjunction isn't necessary and introduces awkwardness.  You could simply say:

> There is no money needed (or *required*), only time.

or

> No money is needed/required, only time.

Comment: ooh.. yeah! sure :D

Comment: Some people would insist on a semicolon or a dash there over a comma.